# Where can I find a list of mountain chains on the Earth?

Tags: geography, mountains, topography

I want to make an app for smartphones that lists the mountain chains of the world.

Where can I find a list of all mountain chains that are presently outspread on the Earth?

Comment: You mean, something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mountain_ranges) / [this](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_de_massifs_et_cha%C3%AEnes_de_montagnes_sur_Terre)?  The discern between «massif» and «chaîne» is a bit difficult, perhaps not only in French, but «cordillère» is more on the side of «mountain chain» (e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cordillera)).

Comment: The [Wikipedia list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mountain_ranges), provided by @Buttonwood is only a partial list. For Australia, it only lists the Great Dividing Range. It excludes all the [mountain ranges of Tasmania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Mountain_ranges_of_Tasmania) and [elsewhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_ranges_of_Australia).

Comment: @Fred I trade Wikipedia like a dictionary of many entries but nevertheless is incomplete; for one that the authors (maybe had to) choose a selection, for the other the authors did not (yet) know about this or that when compiling the entries. So reaching out to a second source (e.g., geographical society, dedicated database) were good, too. With wikipedia's approach to be openly collaborative (e.g. if one topic is explained differently in the English vs one of the non-English editions), blind spots may be easier to correct than if the authors are of one school of thought (or, adhere one dogma).

Comment: Well, if you insist on including mountains in Australia you have the whole world's land surface as mountains ... :-)

Comment: @Earthworm: It all depends on one's definition of a mountain ;-)

Comment: I think the wikipedia list is enought for my app

Comment: @Buttonwood: Not a criticism of you, just an alert to the OP. As other's have stated in comments to other questions here, Wikipedia can sometimes be incomplete or inaccurate. Beware of Wikipedia. :-)